# What colors are supported by slds-progress-bar?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-progressindicator

By default, the progress bar is blue. I am interested in other colors, particularly in red.

[The documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/progress-bar/) only shows an example for "success" (by using the class slds-progress-bar__value_success), which results in green.

Googling gave me various suggestions: info, danger, warning, primary, but these all result in blue progress bars.

This is the relevant piece of HTML:

```
<span class="slds-progress-bar__value slds-progress-bar__value_success" style="width:75%">
```

Has anyone succeeded in getting a progress bar that is neither green nor blue?

Answer (score 2):

you can use a custom style `background`property in the progress bar.

I have tried this and it works properly

```
<template>
<div class="slds-progress-bar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="75" role="progressbar">
  <span class="slds-progress-bar__value" style="width:75%;background:red">
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Progress: 75%</span>
  </span>
</div>
</template>
```

Here is the reference [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/jhzQc3neR/2/edit)

Comment: I have marked your answer as useful (I used it in my code, thank you!), but I cannot mark it as the answer to this question. It is a useful workaround, but it is not the definitive answer.

Comment: I think this is the only answer supported by LWC, this is not a workaround, so kindle please do upvote and mark it as useful answer

Comment: I had already upvoted your answer, someone else had downvoted it before that.

Comment: Can you do it again if possible and mark answere as useful